# The field of Laurent series over $\mathbb{C}$ is quasi-finite

Tags: galois-theory, laurent-series

How can I prove that the field of Laurent series over $\mathbb{C}$ is quasi-finite, which means that it has a unique extension of degree $n$ for all $n \geqslant 1$ ?

The article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-finite_field says that the extension of degree $n$ is $\mathbb{C}((T^{1/n}))$. I think that I understand why it is an extension of degree $n$ (the polynomial $X^n - T$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion ?), but how can I prove that it is unique please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion is a consequence of the ramification theory of valuations: the field of Laurent series $\mathbb{C}((t))$ carries the discrete valuation $v(a_kt^k+a_{k+1}t^{k+1}+\ldots ):=k$, $a_k\neq 0$. It is complete with respect to this valuation; consequently $v$ has a unique extension $w$ to every finite extension field $K$ of $\mathbb{C}((t))$.

Assume $[K:\mathbb{C}((t))]=n$, then by the fundamental equality of valuation theory one has $(\Gamma :\mathbb{Z})[\overline{K}:\mathbb{C}]=n$, where $\Gamma$ is the value group of $w$ and $\overline{K}$ is the residue field of $w$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, one gets $\overline{K}=\mathbb{C}$ and thus $(\Gamma :\mathbb{Z})=n$.

Now assume for the moment that $K/\mathbb{C}((t))$ is Galois. Ramification theory then yields that the Galois group $G$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma /\mathbb{Z}$, which is cyclic of order $n$. In particular every intermediate field of $K/\mathbb{C}((t))$ is Galois with cyclic Galois group.

Since every finite extension $L/\mathbb{C}((t))$ is contained in a finite Galois extension $K/\mathbb{C}((t))$, this shows that every finite extension $L/\mathbb{C}((t))$ is Galois with cyclic Galois group.

Since in a finite cyclic group for every divisor $d$ of the group order there exists exactly one subgroup of index $d$, for every degree $d$ there exists exactly one extension $K/\mathbb{C}((t))$ of degree $d$.

Comment: Thank you. However, I only know the basis of Galois theory. Is there a way to prove the result without the ramification theory of valuations ?

Comment: I see how one can avoid general theory at various points. In particular one can specialize the proof for the fact that the Galois group is cyclic to the present particular case. However in this way one will arrive at a rather lengthy verification. And at the moment I don't see how to avoid using something like Hensel's lemma at the beginning of the whole argument ...